# Does the expansions affect leveling

Tags: guild-wars-2

I played Guild Wars 2 when it still was pay-2-play. Now I've decided to come back and give it a try again. I noticed that there are two expansions and I was wondering if I should pick them up right away. I am reluctant to doing it since from what I could tell, all content in the expansions (except for the extra class) just become relevant once you reach level 80 with one toon. Since I don't have a level 80 character and I wish to level, I'm debating if I should buy the expansions now or wait until I reach 80.

Does the expansions affect leveling in any way or will the leveling experience still be the same weather or not I have them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two expansions, [Heart of Thorns](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Wars_2:_Heart_of_Thorns) and [Path of Fire](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Wars_2:_Path_of_Fire).  Both expansions feature zones and elite specializations for level 80 characters.  The mastery system, including the mount feature of PoF, unlocks when your first character is level 80.

Each purchase of an expansion comes with a level 80 boost, which would immediately allow the account to participate in the max level content and features.

Since you intend to level, you won't miss out on anything if you wait to purchase the expansions.